# DateTime creation in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I need to concatenate a real datetime reference day with a varchar value representing hours/mns informations.

I have read [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) about DateTime operations but haven't find how to do this.

Here is my sample :

```
DECLARE @ref_day [datetime]
DECLARE @hours [varchar](15)
DECLARE @result [datetime]

SET @ref_day = '2015-10-06'
SET @hours = '07:30'

SET @result = ???
```

My expected result is a DateTime object looking like that :

```
@result = 2015/10/06 07:30:00.000
```

Comment: share your expected output.

Comment: In addition, have you seen [`CAST` and `CONVERT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Comment: Expected output is clearly `2015-10-06 07:30:00.000`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @ref_day [datetime]
DECLARE @hours [varchar](15)
DECLARE @result [datetime]

SET @ref_day = '2015-10-06'
SET @hours = '07:30'

SET @result = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @ref_day), @hours)
```

Comment: @rajeshmpanchal Why? It works fine. Just need to declare DECLARE hours varchar(15)

Comment: @MarkSinkinson What do you mean? It will get the expected result. What is the problem?

Comment: @MarkSinkinson Now at least the sample code is complete. I'll leave it to MegaTron to add some explanatory text.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx) SQL Server 2012+:

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372397)**

```
DECLARE @ref_day DATETIME;
DECLARE @hours VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @result DATETIME;

SET @ref_day = '2015-10-06'
SET @hours = '07:30';

SELECT @result = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@ref_day),
                                   MONTH(@ref_day),
                                   DAY(@ref_day),
                                   DATEPART(hh,@hours),
                                   DATEPART(mi, @hours),
                                   0,
                                   0);

SELECT @result;
```

Comment: DATETIMEFROMPARTS not supported in all SQL Server version.

Answer (score 0):

You can add seconds to `@hours` variable and convert It to time, then concat with `@ref_day` in following:

```
DECLARE @ref_day [datetime]
DECLARE @hours varchar(20)
DECLARE @result [datetime]

SET @ref_day = '2015-10-06'
SET @hours = '07:30'

SET @result = @ref_day + ' ' + cast(@hours + ':00' as time)

SELECT @result
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2015-10-06 07:30:00.000
```

Comment: Who downvoted working solution without explaination?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below query

```
DECLARE @ref_day [datetime]
DECLARE @hours [varchar](15)
DECLARE @result [datetime]

SET @ref_day = '2015-10-06'
SET @hours = '07:30'

SET @result = @ref_day + @hours

SELECT FORMAT(@result,'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.000', 'en-us')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add 2 datetimes, simply convert time to datetime and add them like this:

```
DECLARE @ref_day datetime = '2015-10-06'
DECLARE @hours   varchar(15) = '07:30'

SELECT @ref_day +cast(@hours as datetime)
```

Result:

```
2015-10-06 07:30
```